# Best software tool to process image/video and obtain greatest level of zoom?

Tags: video

I would like to get advice on what is the best software to obtain the best level of zoom possible for a video.

Do I need to resample the video? Are there tools that can do this live? (maybe selecting just the small part of the screen I am interested in?)

Please note I am not asking about a quick zoom, which I can get with any media player, but I need an actual "processing" which will allow me to perceive more detail.

What's the market top solution, and what's the open source top solution?

Comment: Just to point out, no matter the software, the resulting image is still a 'guess' of what was really captured. There is no way to recreate detail when data isn't there. There is no CSI "Enhance" - only a best-guess that a computer can make.

Comment: Yea I was asking on regard to this, which was the software that is industrially recognized as the best at interpolating/guessing the pixels so that the final impression on the human eye is to have a nicer (apparently more detailed) level of zoom in contrast to some other software.

Answer (score 2):

You need to scale and/or crop with the best video solution. None of them do it live.

1. Top market solution:

> - any [Autodesk Video Solution](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/index?siteID=123112&id=17801117) (Smoke,Flint,Flame,Fire,Inferno). The number of options for the resample alghoritm is amazing... More than eight(*8*)!

1. Top open-source solution:

> - [Blender](http://www.blender.org/), used as a video-editor.

I'm sure you can easily find live solutions too, but not with the same level of quality, without going to a hardware-based solution like [Blackmagic](http://www.blackmagic-design.com/products/ultrastudio3d/).

Comment: I think it is good to mention here: scale and crop in autodesk machines usually are realtime, or very near realtime. This is not called "live". It is called realtime rendering.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand just what zoom processing software can do for you. If we exclude some highly specialist areas with supercomputers (eg NSA and others who can interpolate successive frames to gain more detail - to provide a higher resolution single frame) **any software zoom you carry out will lose detail**.

Any algorithm which carries out a zoom works with the detail already in the video - from a basic one which just makes the pixels bigger, to an interpolating algorithm which tries to blend between pixels.

The only solution if you actually want a zoom is to **use a more powerful lens** on the original recording device. Once the recording is on media you are limited to the amount of information on the media - to get higher zoom resolution you would need to recreate information...just doesn't happen, I'm afraid.

Comment: @jj_  I have deleted your comment because it was a bit rude.  I encourage you to rephrase your comment and post it again.  (from the FAQ under the Etiquette section "_Civility is required at all times; rudeness will not be tolerated._").